# td background image 100% not working in ie 8 (figures)

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-table

I have a td that i want the background image to be 100% no repeat.

The code below works on everything but ie8 +-. don't know about ie10 as i am running on a xp pro server.

```
 .td1 {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

  }

  <td class="td1" style="max-height: 100%; max-width: 100%" background="../art1/#bg1mg#.jpg" align="center">
```

as the image changes with the variable "bg1mg" in the td tag i cannot enter image url in the styles section.

tnx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 does not support `background-size`.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts

Tip: Also you should not mix HTML with CSS. Separate your content from your styling. It's easy to maintain and will save you from a lot of headaches.

Comment: as far as mixing class and style in tags it is often necessary when you have a class description but each input needs a different width and the "size" tag isn't accurate enough for fine tuning with cross browser issues.